# implementing an ordered cache using guava

Tags: java, guava

I am trying to process some interim data in the background to avoid performance issue on the main thread.

The plan is to collect data and process it in the background by maintaining the insertion order.
The oldest message should be processed first. Read and write to the cache are happening simultaneously. The performance is the key here.

Is there a way to achieve this using guava caching?

Here is the code I have so far:

```java
public static Cache<String, String> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
      .maximumSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
      .concurrencyLevel(5)
      .removalListener(notification -> {
        System.out.println("REMOVE : " + notification.getKey() + " CAUSE :" + notification.getCause().name());
      })
      .build();

// Different threads are adding data to this queue by calling
cache.put(key, value);

// The worker thread
public void run() {

    while (true) {
      if (cache.size() > 0) {
        final ConcurrentMap<String, String> cacheMap = cache.asMap();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : cacheMap.entrySet()) {
          //send data to a different system.
          cache.invalidate(entry.getKey());
        }
      } else {
        // Add delay of 5 sec
        Thread.sleep(5000);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want a cache and not a queue?

Comment: Even I think queue would be a perfect fit, but read from the queue would remove the element and in case of processing failure If I want to retain the message in the queue itself so that I can retry in the next attempt I would have to compromise  with the order.  Guava cache gives me a flexibility of reading the data as map and process it. On successful processing I can call cache.invalidate(message) so that it would be removed from the cache else, next time I call cachec.asMap() it would still be there.

Comment: @Samar This would be a useful edit to your question, as well as any other detail you can give, such as the code you may have written so far, or a sketched API.

Comment: @MikaelF I have provided my sample implementation, which is not doing ordered processing.

Comment: Is the order of processing absolutely paramount? Could you not just re-add a failed task back to the end of the queue?